# accessing text file from client getting different data than accessing it on server

Tags: php, fopen, file-get-contents, fread

I have this code on the server

```
<?php
   $file = fopen("data.txt","w+") or die("Couldn't locate file");
   fwrite($data);       
   fclose($file);
?>
```

and this one on the localhost on my local machine

```
<?php
   $file = fopen('http://x.x.x.x/data.txt','r'); 
   echo fgets($file);
   fclose($file);
?>
```

The problem I face - and haven't been able to figure out - is: whenever I change the data in the text file on the server, it takes a while to read the change on localhost side.

Now the database option had a huge delay so it's not an option and i have tried mostly everything i can think of, so i was wondering what i am doing wrong and if their is a better way.

Comment: PHP works only on the server

Comment: im sorry my bad i was referring to localhost on my local machine

Comment: If for _it takes a while to read the chenge from the client side_ you're referring to the fact that you have to click the **Update** the browser many times before it gets the data updated, it may be a browser Cache issue

Comment: But how do you have that file synced with localhost and a remote server?

Comment: @eisa i use ajax to keep calling the text file over and over again to check for data

Comment: @tas9 well i've tried to empty the cache and nothing, i've tried using different browsers same issue

Comment: Have you tried the conventional unique id `www.mysite.com?929292` method?

Comment: my problem isn't the method i've tried ajax jasonp, converted it to rss and then called it same problem but every new method i use it only works once, i actually dont know whats the problem in reading the file again after changing it

Answer (score 0):

Well i dont know what was the problem but it worked for some reason, maybe something was wrong with the server itself.